bash: if $i equals any command line argument: if [[ " $@ " =~ " $i " ]]
To check if $i equals any command line argument (in a Bash script), I use
 if [[ " $@ " =~ " $i " ]]

Is there a better way?
I mean, a way that is more recommendable, more general, or the like, yet almost as simple.
If I am correct, the above works when $i and each command line argument do not contain spaces. That is fine in most cases, but maybe there is a simple fix to that or some other simple improvement.
In that special case, I think that $* works equally well, but is either more recommendable in general?
Their difference can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898665/what-is-in-bash

You'd get a more reliable result if you converted both to shell-quoted strings. In bash 5.x, this might be [[ " ${@@Q} " = *" ${i@Q} "* ]] -- that way you avoid spaces that are data and spaces that are syntax being confused for each other.

If switching to zsh is an option, then it should just be:
set 'foo bar' 1:2 $'a\nb'
i='foo bar'
if (( n = $argv[(Ie)$i] )); then
  print -r -- "$i is found among the positional parameters, in \${$n} at least"
fi

In zsh, the positional parameters are also available in the $argv array like in csh. The I array subscript flag causes the subscript to be treated as a pattern and the expansion to return the Index of the last element whose value matches the pattern (or 0 if not found). The e is for exact match instead of pattern match. Here, we assign the result to n inside a ksh-style arithmetic expression (which returns true if the expression resolves to a non-zero value as usual).
In zsh, it's also possible to construct a pattern that matches any element of $@ with:
pattern="(${(j[|])${(b)@}})"

There, the b parameter expansion flag escapes the glob, j[|] joins the resulting elements with |, so you end up with a (foo|bar|\*|) pattern after set -- foo bar '*' '' for instance.
To be used as:
if [[ $i = $~pattern ]]...

Note however that if the list of positional parameters is empty, you end with () as the pattern which would incorrectly match on the empty string.
If the point ultimately is to find which of the elements of an array are also found among the positional parameters, you can use zsh's array intersection operator: ${A:*B}.
set a A 'x y'
array=(a b 'x y' a)
print -r Found in argv: ${array:*argv}

In bash or any POSIX shell, if there's a character you know doesn't occur in $i or any of the positional parameters, you can do something like:
IFS=: # join "$*" with :
case ":${*}:" in
  (*:"$i":*) printf '%s\n' "$i is among the positional parameters";;
esac

Similar to your approach except it uses standard sh syntax rather than the [[ ... ]] kshism and the non-portable (even across bash versions) =~ (=~ also chokes on non-text strings compared to the simpler = there in bash), here we're fixing the separator to : instead of space which is as arbitrary, it's down to you to know which is least likely to occur in $i or a positional parameter in your use case. Using "$@" outside of list contexts also makes little sense and the behaviour varies from shell to shell. "$*" makes sense in non-list contexts where it is clearly specified to join the positional parameters with the first character of $IFS.
You can use the ksh-style [[ ... ]] instead of case with:
if [[ ":${*}:" = *:"$i":* ]]...

To be able to work arbitrary values, in bash you'd have to use a loop:
found=false
for arg do
  if [ "$arg" = "$i" ]; then
    found=true
    break
  fi
done
if "$found"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$i is among the positional parameters"
fi

You could also define a helper function:
among() {
  local needle="$1" arg
  shift
  for arg do
    [ "$arg" = "$needle" ] && return
  done
  false
}

if among "$i" "$@"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$i is among the positional parameters"
fi



To check if $i equals any command line argument (in a Bash script), I use
if [[ " $@ " =~ " $i " ]]


At best this will look to see if the command line contains the value of $i. For example, if you have i=the and one of the command line arguments is the elephant the condition will match.
However, you're also using $@ which, when used inside double quotes, usually expands to be a series of quoted argument words. Here I would expect you to be using "$*". (With bash the [[ … ]] does the right thing and uses $@ as a  single string, but that doesn't mean it's correct to use $@.)
Better would be this, but it still suffers from the contains rather than equals:
if [[ " $* " =~ " $i " ]]

To check whether $i equals any of the command line arguments I think you will have to iterate across the set:
success=false
for arg in "$@"; do [[ "$arg" = "$i" ]] && { success=true; break; }; done

if "$success"

This is more elegantly expressed in another answer as the function among.
